# remove duplicate rows from a table given certain criteria in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, mysql-5.7

I have a table, named books, with rows like:

```
+----+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
Id    PNo        Gid      Genre    Trailer
+----+----------+---------+--------+------------+
1     1234567      55        NULL      NULL
2     1234567      64        Fiction   NULL
3     8763525      64        Fiction   NULL
4     8763525      73        Fiction   NULL
5     5555555      18        Fiction   NULL
6     5555555      64        Fiction   NULL
+---------------------------------------------------
```

What i need to do, is the following:
i want to remove all rows, that have duplicate data, based on column PNo, and where the Gid value = 64, and also Pno is not 5555555

The following query returns to me the results i need (the duplicate rows), but i need to know how i could make the deletion based also on the above criteria:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as repetitions,
  group_concat(PNo, ' (', Gid, ', ', Genre, ') ' SEPARATOR ' | ')
    as row_data
FROM books
GROUP BY PNo
HAVING repetitions > 1;

DELETE m1 FROM books m1
INNER JOIN books m2 
ON m1.PNo = m2.PNo
WHERE m1.PNo = '64' AND m1.PNo != 5555555
```

The above will delete all rows, that have a m1.PNo = '64', when i need to remove only the duplicate rows, based on the value of the PNo column, that also have in the column Gid the value 64. How my delete query should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there: you just need a condition that avoids that a record can be joined with itself. Assuming that `id` is the primary key of your table (or at least a unique key), you could do:

```
delete m1 
from books m1
inner join books m2 on m1.pno = m2.pno and m1.id <> m2.id
where m1.gid = 64 and m1.pno != 5555555
```

Note: I think that there is a glitch in your `where` clause, where `m1.PNo = '64'` should be `m1.gid = 64` (also, if `gid` is of a numeric datatype, you should not quote the value).